# Facing issues integrating PCL with ROS

Tags: python, pcl, catkin-make, ros-noetic, pcl-ros

I am trying to use PCL filters in my rosnode ,where I am trying to perform noise removal on the pointcloud,but while building the package. I am getting CMAKE errors

```
#include <pcl/filters/statistical_outlier_removal.h>

pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ> sor;
sor.setInputCloud(cloud_msg);
sor.setMeanK(50);  // Number of neighbors to consider for mean distance estimation
sor.setStddevMulThresh(1.0); // Standard deviation threshold
sor.filter(*cloud_msg); // Apply the noise filter
```

Here is the catkin_make output:

```
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python3
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/em.py
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ketan/MiDaS/ros/build/test_results
-- Forcing gtest/gmock from source, though one was otherwise available.
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3 (found version "3.8.10") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests3
-- catkin 0.8.10
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - midas_cpp
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'midas_cpp'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(midas_cpp)
-- Caffe2: CUDA detected: 12.2
-- Caffe2: CUDA nvcc is: /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
-- Caffe2: CUDA toolkit directory: /usr/local/cuda
-- Caffe2: Header version is: 12.2
-- /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnvrtc.so shorthash is 000ca627
-- USE_CUDNN is set to 0. Compiling without cuDNN support
-- Autodetected CUDA architecture(s):  6.1
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: -gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3, version: 3.3.7)
-- FLANN found (include: /usr/include, lib: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflann_cpp.so)
-- The imported target "vtkParseOGLExt" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtkParseOGLExt-7.1"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "vtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "pvtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/pvtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-7.1/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- OpenNI found (version: 1.5.4.0, include: /usr/include/ni, lib: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;libusb::libusb)
-- OpenNI2 found (version: 2.2.0.33, include: /usr/include/openni2, lib: /usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so;libusb::libusb)
-- Could NOT find Pcap (missing: PCAP_LIBRARIES PCAP_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
-- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3, version: 3.3.7)
-- OpenNI found (version: 1.5.4.0, include: /usr/include/ni, lib: /usr/lib/libOpenNI.so;libusb::libusb)
-- OpenNI2 found (version: 2.2.0.33, include: /usr/include/openni2, lib: /usr/lib/libOpenNI2.so;libusb::libusb)
-- Could NOT find Qhull (missing: QHULL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** surface features related to qhull will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_KDTREE
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_SEARCH
-- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
-- looking for PCL_FILTERS
-- looking for PCL_2D
-- looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- looking for PCL_FEATURES
-- looking for PCL_ML
-- looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
-- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
-- looking for PCL_SURFACE
-- looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
-- looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
-- looking for PCL_TRACKING
-- looking for PCL_RECOGNITION
-- looking for PCL_STEREO
-- looking for PCL_OUTOFCORE
-- looking for PCL_PEOPLE
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Configuring done (1.6s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ketan/MiDaS/ros/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j12 -l12" in "/home/ketan/MiDaS/ros/build"
####
[ 25%] Built target camera_bringup
[ 50%] Built target realsense2_camera
[ 62%] Linking CXX executable /home/ketan/MiDaS/ros/devel/lib/midas_cpp/depth_pcl
[ 87%] Built target midas_cpp
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.2, needed by /opt/ros/noetic/lib/libcv_bridge.so, may conflict with libopencv_imgcodecs.so.408
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.408, needed by /home/ketan/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.8.0, may conflict with libopencv_core.so.4.2
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o: in function `DepthPcl::stateCallback(ros::TimerEvent const&)':
depth_pcl.cpp:(.text+0x7d1): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o: in function `pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZ>::filter(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&)':
depth_pcl.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEE6filterERNS_10PointCloudIS1_EE[_ZN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEE6filterERNS_10PointCloudIS1_EE]+0x38): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::initCompute()'
/usr/bin/ld: depth_pcl.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEE6filterERNS_10PointCloudIS1_EE[_ZN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEE6filterERNS_10PointCloudIS1_EE]+0x205): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::deinitCompute()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o: in function `pcl::Filter<pcl::PointXYZ>::Filter(bool)':
depth_pcl.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEC2Eb[_ZN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEC5Eb]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::PCLBase()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o: in function `void pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::assign<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pcl::PointXYZ const*, std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ> > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pcl::PointXYZ const*, std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<pcl::PointXYZ const*, std::vector<pcl::PointXYZ, Eigen::aligned_allocator<pcl::PointXYZ> > >, int)':
depth_pcl.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl10PointCloudINS_8PointXYZEE6assignIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKS1_St6vectorIS1_N5Eigen17aligned_allocatorIS1_EEEEEEEvT_SE_i[_ZN3pcl10PointCloudINS_8PointXYZEE6assignIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKS1_St6vectorIS1_N5Eigen17aligned_allocatorIS1_EEEEEEEvT_SE_i]+0x36): undefined reference to `pcl::console::print(pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL, char const*, ...)'
/usr/bin/ld: depth_pcl.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl10PointCloudINS_8PointXYZEE6assignIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKS1_St6vectorIS1_N5Eigen17aligned_allocatorIS1_EEEEEEEvT_SE_i[_ZN3pcl10PointCloudINS_8PointXYZEE6assignIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKS1_St6vectorIS1_N5Eigen17aligned_allocatorIS1_EEEEEEEvT_SE_i]+0x129): undefined reference to `pcl::console::print(pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL, char const*, ...)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointIndices const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x48): undefined reference to `pcl::FilterIndices<pcl::PointXYZ>::applyFilter(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointIndices const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl13FilterIndicesINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x48): undefined reference to `pcl::FilterIndices<pcl::PointXYZ>::applyFilter(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointIndices const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl6FilterINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x20): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setInputCloud(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x28): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x30): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x38): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(std::shared_ptr<pcl::PointIndices const> const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE[_ZTVN3pcl7PCLBaseINS_8PointXYZEEE]+0x40): undefined reference to `pcl::PCLBase<pcl::PointXYZ>::setIndices(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/src/depth_pcl.cpp.o: in function `pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ>::applyFilter(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)':
depth_pcl.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEE11applyFilterERSt6vectorIiSaIiEE[_ZN3pcl25StatisticalOutlierRemovalINS_8PointXYZEE11applyFilterERSt6vectorIiSaIiEE]+0x23): undefined reference to `pcl::StatisticalOutlierRemoval<pcl::PointXYZ>::applyFilterIndices(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [midas_cpp/CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/build.make:187: /home/ketan/MiDaS/ros/devel/lib/midas_cpp/depth_pcl] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:2579: midas_cpp/CMakeFiles/depth_pcl.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j12 -l12" failed
```

From this I understand that it's not able to find the library, or the library is not linked correctly.

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(midas_cpp)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/libtorch")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/librealsense")
link_directories("/usr/local/include/pcl-1.13/")

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/include/")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/lib")

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(realsense2 REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL)
find_package(pcl_ros)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})


include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(midas_cpp src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(midas_cpp "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}" "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET midas_cpp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(realsense2_camera src/realsense_bringup.cpp)
target_link_libraries(realsense2_camera "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}" realsense2::realsense2)
set_property(TARGET realsense2_camera PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(camera_bringup src/camera_bringup.cpp)
target_link_libraries(camera_bringup "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}" )
set_property(TARGET camera_bringup PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)


add_executable(depth_pcl src/depth_pcl.cpp)
target_link_libraries(depth_pcl "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET depth_pcl PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)


#############
## Install ##
#############


#############
## Testing ##
#############

# catkin_package()
```

I did some google search and have tried various solutions like adding pcl_ros to find packages, adding it in package.xml, adding PCL_LIBRARIES in target_link_libraries. Nothing seems to work.

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I just changed the order of arrangements in CMakeLists.txt

This is what worked for me,

```
# cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(midas_cpp)

list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/libtorch")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "~/librealsense")
link_directories("/usr/local/include/pcl-1.13/")
link_directories("/usr/local/lib/")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/include/")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/lib")
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/lib")



find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(realsense2 REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  PCL
)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})


include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
 LIBRARIES midas_cpp pcl_ros_filters pcl_ros_io pcl_ros_tf
 CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs pcl_ros
 DEPENDS PCL
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(midas_cpp src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(midas_cpp "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}" "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET midas_cpp PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(realsense2_camera src/realsense_bringup.cpp)
target_link_libraries(realsense2_camera "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}" realsense2::realsense2)
set_property(TARGET realsense2_camera PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

# add_executable(depth_image src/depth_image.cpp)
# target_link_libraries(depth_image "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}")
# set_property(TARGET depth_image PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)


add_executable(camera_bringup src/camera_bringup.cpp)
target_link_libraries(camera_bringup "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}" )
set_property(TARGET camera_bringup PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)


# add_executable(depth2cloud src/depth2cloud.cpp)
# target_link_libraries(depth2cloud "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}")
# set_property(TARGET depth2cloud PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)

message("${PCL_LIBRARIES}")
add_executable(depth_pcl src/depth_pcl.cpp)
target_link_libraries(depth_pcl "${OpenCV_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES}")
```

Comment: If you add `pcl_ros` to your `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS` you can remove all the PCL related stuff, like `DEPENDS PCL`, `add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})` and `include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})` as catkin would do that for you

Comment: Go it. Thanks!!